# recursive file search with wildcard(*) matching

Tags: java, recursion, wildcard

I wrote this code to search files:

```
package filesearch;

import java.io.File;

public class FileSearch {

    public void walk(String path, String partOfFile) {
        File root = new File(path);
        File[] list = root.listFiles();

        if (list == null)
            return;

        for (File f : list) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                walk(f.getAbsolutePath(), partOfFile);
            } else {
                if (f.getAbsolutePath().contains(partOfFile)) {
                    System.out.println("File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileSearch fw = new FileSearch();
        fw.walk("g:\\", "abs");
    }
}
```

I want to use wildcard(*). then if(*) is the first or last character of the pattern I can implement it by adding this code:

```
if(f.getAbsolutePath().startsWith(partOfFile)){
    System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
}
if(f.getAbsolutePath().endWith(partOfFile)){
    System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
}
```

How do I handle when I have more that one wildcard(*) and When wildcards(*) are in the middle of the pattern?

Comment: convert your pattern to a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Try this program.

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileSearch
{

public void walk( String path, String partOfFile )
{
    File root = new File( path );
    File[] list = root.listFiles();
    if ( list == null )
        return;

    for ( File f : list )
    {
        if ( f.isDirectory() )
        {
            walk( f.getAbsolutePath(), partOfFile );
        }
        else
        {
            boolean isFileMatched = isFileMatched( f, partOfFile);
            if ( isFileMatched )
                System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
        }
    }
}

private boolean isFileMatched( File file, String partOfFile )
{
    boolean isMatched = true;
    if ( file == null || partOfFile == null )
        return false;

    String fileName = file.getName();

    //to ignore extension
    if ( fileName.contains( "." ) )
        fileName = fileName.substring( 0, fileName.lastIndexOf( "." ) );

    String[] tokens = null;
    if ( partOfFile.contains( "*" ) )
    {
        if ( partOfFile.startsWith( "*" ) && partOfFile.endsWith( "*" ) )
        {
            tokens = partOfFile.split( "\\*" );
            isMatched = isTokenMatched( isMatched, fileName, tokens );
        }
        else if ( partOfFile.startsWith( "*" ) )
        {
            String suffix = partOfFile.substring( partOfFile.lastIndexOf( "*" ) + 1 );
            if ( fileName.endsWith( suffix ) )
            {
                tokens = partOfFile.split( "\\*" );
                isMatched = isTokenMatched( isMatched, fileName, tokens );
            }
            else
                isMatched = false;
        }
        else if ( partOfFile.endsWith( "*" ) )
        {
            String prefix = partOfFile.substring( 0, partOfFile.indexOf( "*" ) );
            if ( fileName.startsWith( prefix ) )
            {
                tokens = partOfFile.split( "\\*" );
                isMatched = isTokenMatched( isMatched, fileName, tokens );
            }
            else
                isMatched = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( !fileName.equals( partOfFile ) )
                isMatched = false;
        }
    }
    return isMatched;
}

private boolean isTokenMatched( boolean isMatched, String fileName, String[] tokens )
{
    if ( tokens != null )
    {
        for ( String token : tokens )
        {
            if ( !fileName.contains( token ) )
            {
                isMatched = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return isMatched;
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    FileSearch fw = new FileSearch();
   fw.walk("g:\\" , "abs");
}
}
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation about how and why this is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are many other ways to get what you wanted done, but converting your pattern with a wildcard to a regex is most efficient in terms of coding and readability.Just the way you have used startsWith and endWith, you can use matches function and a regular expression to quickly verify what you wanted.

All you have to do is replace `*` in the pattern with `.*?`. This way your pattern with wildcard will be converted into a non greedy regular expression. Then it is just a matter of using a function to verify if the pattern exists in your string. Below example verifies if there is a * in the middle. This approach will work with any number of wildcards.

```
partOfFile = ".*?"+partOfFile.replace("*",".*?")+".*?";  // fi*e.log becomes .*?fi.*e.log.*?
if(f.getAbsolutePath().matches(partOfFile))
{
    System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
}
```

matches function will take a regular expression as an input. We are placing a .*? before and after the pattern to ensure that we can have some characters before and after the pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Use [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to filter the Filenames.

Answer (score -1):

Use Files.newDirectoryStream(Path, String glob)

More information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream(java.nio.file.Path, java.lang.String)

Comment: It don't support more than One \*

Comment: Yes it does: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#glob

Comment: @BartEnkelaar Globs *do* support multiple *s. However, newDirectoryStream only iterates over the given directory.